# vuejs slot are not reactive to dynamic data being passed from parent

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am passing a variable (from parent component) to slot of a child component. During initial rendering this variable get correctly displayed.

But when the variable being passed changes in parent, this change is not reflected in child component, below is my code

```
<template>
  <div>
    <v-client-table
     :columns="columns"
     v-model="data"
     :options="options"
     :class="{ 'ready' : isReady }"
    >
    <div slot="h__select">
      <input type="checkbox" @change="selectAll($event)" 
      :checked="allSelected" />
    </div>
 ....
```

The variable is "allSelected". How can I bind the "checked" attribute to the value of "allSelected" variable. I have searched extensively but couldn't find anything similar. Please help.

Comment: If `allSelected` is a prop in this template then it will be automatically updated by Vue when the parent component providing this prop changes the value.

Comment: @IVO GELOV I tried that by passing :allSelected="allSelected" to v-client-table component and the doing slot-scope="{allSelected}"  on <div slot="h__select" slot-scope="{allSelected}">, still didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Use the following technique:

```html
<template>
<!-- This is the higher-order component V-CLIENT-TABLE -->
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>
          <slot name="h__select" :allSelected="all" />
        </th>
        <!-- Produce the header here -->
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr v-for="(item,index) in items" :key="index">
        <slot :item="item" />
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</template>

<script>
export default
{
  name: 'VClientTable',
  props:
  {
    items:
    {
      type: Array,
      default: () => []
    },
    columns:
    {
      type: Array,
      default: () => []
    },
  },
  data()
  {
    return {
      all: false,
    };
  },
  watch:
  {
    all(newValue, oldValue)
    {
      // update checkboxes for all rows
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

```html
<template>
<!-- This is the component where you use V-CLIENT-TABLE -->
  <div>
    <v-client-table
     :columns="columns"
     v-model="data"
     :options="options"
     :class="{ 'ready' : isReady }"
    >
    <div slot="h__select" slot-scope="data">
      <input type="checkbox" @change="data.allSelected = !data.allSelected" 
      :checked="data.allSelected" />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default
{
  name: 'ChildComponent',
}
</script>
```